Ensure that the MassTransit bus has started correctly and has all the defined consumers configured
I’m using MassTransit 8.0.15 with RabbitMQ in a .NET REST API. During startup, I configure several consumers and activities used within a routing slip. Occasionally, it happens that a queue (for activity-completed messages) has no consumer bound to it. When I restart the application, it binds correctly. It seems like a timeout issue or something similar. The problem is that my application starts, but some parts may not be properly configured, causing me to miss messages or preventing my routing slip from completing.
I’m unsure why this is happening, but I also have another question. Is there a way in MassTransit to verify if the startup was successful, ensuring that everything is configured as expected? Or should I 'manually' test it by sending messages to each queue to check if they respond?
Another question relates to the UseMessageRetry method. Can I apply it globally to ensure that every message has a retry policy? I’m specifically asking if it can also cover all startup TCP connections that configure queues, exchanges, activities, etc.

You can configure the host options so that the .NET Generic Host waits until the bus has successfully started before continuing with the ASP.NET startup. By default, this is false.
services.AddOptions<MassTransitHostOptions>()
    .Configure(options =>
    {
        options.WaitUntilStarted = true;
        options.StartTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
    });


I tried with WaitUntilStarted=true. The problem is that in some cases errors are in DBG level and they doesnt block application startup. For example: [2024/09/25 15:41:19 DBG] MassTransit   Endpoint Faulted: "rabbitmq://***/update-identity_execute?temporary=true"
MassTransit.RabbitMqConnectionException: ReceiveTransport faulted: @:6100/vhost
---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply(TimeSpan timeout)
[2024/09/25 15:41:26 INF] MassTransit   Bus started: "rabbitmq://***:6100/vhost"
